# Swift “UDP Read” code - unsaferawbufferpointer compile error

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, udp

I’m sure someone can solve this in seconds but I’m very new to swift, using playgrounds on the iPad. I’m trying to modify some SendUDP code to recieve instead, but I can’t solve the compile error (unsafepointer is not convertible to unsaferawbufferpointer) on the readResult= line. The SEND works fine with very similar code, but I’m really struggling here, way out of my depth...

Here’s the code

```js
func readUDP() {
  guard
  let addresses =
    try ? addressesFor(host: "192.168.4.1", port: 80)
  else {
    print("host not found")
    return
  }
  if addresses.count != 1 {
    print("host ambiguous; using the first one")
  }
  address = addresses[0]
  fd1 = socket(Int32(address.ss_family), SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
  guard fd1 >= 0
  else {
    print("`socket` failed`")
    return
  }
  defer {
    let junk = close(fd1)
    assert(junk == 0)
  }

  var message = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 1024)
  let messageCount = message.count
  var readResult = message.withUnsafeBytes {
    (messagePtr: UnsafePointer < UInt8 > ) - > Int in
      return address.withSockAddr {
        (sa, saLen) - > Int in
          return recvfrom(fd1, messagePtr, messageCount, 0, sa, & saLen)
      }
  }
  guard readResult >= 0
  else {
    print("read failed")
    return
  }
  print("success")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swift's [implicit bridging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer#overview) to simplify to something like this:

```
var message = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 1024)
  let messageCount = message.count
  var readResult = address.withSockAddr {
    (sa, saLen) - > Int in
      return recvfrom(fd1, &message, messageCount, 0, sa, &saLen)
  }
  guard readResult >= 0
  else {
    print("read failed")
    return
  }
```